# Is is possible to pre-authorize delayed in-app payments using Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment, stripe-payments, applepay

Is it possible to make user pre-authorize a payment in an app but the actual payment occurs at a specified later date? User will know when the payment actually takes place when she authorizes the payment.

This is not regular recurring subscription, but more like one-off payments user can make at any interval.

If not, is there a payment solution that can be integrated with iOS and offers this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Using Stripe, you can save the Apple Pay token to a customer and charge it at any time. Authorization and Capture is supported with Stripe but you have to capture the funds within 7 days of authorizing it.